# AOSP my app is not included in system build

Tags: android, makefile, kernel, system, android-source

I'm building a custom ROM and would like to include a simple launcher I built as a system app. Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# General
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Tott
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

# To make system app
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Home Launcher2 Launcher3

# src/res files
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

# libraries
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v7-appcompat

#flags
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay \
    --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat 

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

I have placed the Android.mk, AndroidManifest.xml, res folder, and src (containing java) in a directory called Tott which has been placed in [source]/packages/apps. I've also added Tott to PRODUCT_PACKAGES at [source]/build/target/product/core.mk

When I build the android system.img, it says that that it is including [source]/packages/apps/Tott/Android.mk in terminal but my app never shows in [source]/out/target/product/*vender*/system/app or priv-app. I'm also able to build my app successfully by simply running make Tott at [source].

What am I doing wrong here????

Thanks

Comment: Your Android.mk file looks similar to ones I have written.  I will say that I've seen strange behavior when specifying LOCAL_SDK_VERSION, so I stopped including that line.  I've also never used LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE.  Everything else looks normal to me.  Have you tried cding into your app directory and running the "mm" command?  Does mm build and place your app in the correct place?

Comment: One other thing to check, I see you are overriding Launcher2 and Launcher3.  If you delete those apps under /out/.../system/priv-app, do they reappear after you run a build?  If they do that means make does not like your Android.mk file for whatever reason because those app are not being overridden like you are requesting.

Comment: Thanks! Commenting out the LOCAL_SDK_VERSION & LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE did the trick

Comment: Awesome!  Let's turn that into an answer and you can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out LOCAL_SDK_VERSION and LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE. I don't use those in my Android.mk files and I never have a problem.

Comment: And after further digging, I actually found that it was the LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE specifically that was causing the issue. Thanks